# In statsmoldes, how is the moving average model implemented?

Tags: moving-average

From wikipedia, I checked a moving average model definition.

I attempted to examine the implementation of the moving average model of statsmodels in order to understand it definitely.

https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/blob/main/statsmodels/tsa/statespace/sarimax.py

But, it is difficult to locate the code on how to calculate the moving average coefficients. I believe my knowledge of code and formula is lacking.

Has anyone looked over the code for the moving average model?